# Heap corruption and other problems

Tags: c++, oop, heap-memory

I just started to learn OOP and I have some problems with my first project. It does not run everytime, but when it runs, it displays the right values.
When it does not run, it seems that the problem is the cout, tough I overloaded <<.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

class Numar_Complex {
    double re, im;
public:
    Numar_Complex() { this->im = 0; this->re = 0; }
    Numar_Complex(Numar_Complex const &n){
            this->re = n.re;
            this->im = n.im;
        }
    ~Numar_Complex() = default;
    double Modul();
    Numar_Complex operator + (Numar_Complex const& obj) {
        Numar_Complex res;
        res.re = this->re + obj.re;
        res.im = this->im + obj.im;
        return res;
    }
    Numar_Complex operator *(Numar_Complex const& obj) {
        Numar_Complex res;
        res.re = this->re * obj.re - this->im * obj.im;
        res.im = this->re * obj.im + this->im * obj.re;
        return res;
    }
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, Numar_Complex & obj) {
        out << obj.re << " + i * " << obj.im;
        return out;
    }
    friend istream& operator >>(istream& in, Numar_Complex &obj) {
        in >> obj.re >> obj.im;
        return in;
    }
    void operator =(const Numar_Complex& x) {
        this->re = x.re;
        this->im = x.im;
    }
};

class Vector_Complex : public Numar_Complex {
    int len;
    Numar_Complex* v;
public:
    Vector_Complex();
    Vector_Complex(Numar_Complex const &x, int n);
    Vector_Complex(Vector_Complex &w);
    ~Vector_Complex() = default;
    double* Get_VectorOfModules();
    int Get_Len() {
        return len;
    }
    void Sort();
    Numar_Complex Sum_Vector();
    Numar_Complex Prod_Scalar(Vector_Complex const&a, Vector_Complex const&b);
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, Vector_Complex const& w) {
        out << w.len << "\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < w.len; i++)
            out << w.v[i] << " ";
        return out;
    }
    friend istream& operator >>(istream& in, Vector_Complex & w) {
        in >> w.len;
        for (int i = 0; i < w.len; i++)
            in >> w.v[i];
        return in;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Vector_Complex Vec;
    cin >> Vec;
    cout << Vec << "\n" << "\n";
    double* p = Vec.Get_VectorOfModules();
    int n = Vec.Get_Len();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++, p++)
        cout << *p << " ";
    p -= n;
    delete[] p;
    return 0;
}


double Numar_Complex::Modul() {
    return sqrt(this->re * this->re + this->im * this->im);
}

Vector_Complex::Vector_Complex() {
    len = 0;
    v = new Numar_Complex[0];
}

Vector_Complex::Vector_Complex(Numar_Complex const &x, int n) {
    len = n;
    v = new Numar_Complex[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        v[i] = x;
}

Vector_Complex::Vector_Complex(Vector_Complex &w) {
    len = w.len;
    v = new Numar_Complex[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        v[i] = w.v[i];
}

double* Vector_Complex::Get_VectorOfModules() {
    double* w = new double[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        w[i] = v[i].Modul();
    return w;
}

void Vector_Complex::Sort() {

}

Numar_Complex Vector_Complex::Sum_Vector() {
    Numar_Complex s;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        s = s + v[i];
    return s;
}

Numar_Complex Vector_Complex::Prod_Scalar(Vector_Complex const& a, Vector_Complex const& b) {
    Numar_Complex prod;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.len; i++)
        prod = prod + a.v[i] * b.v[i];
    return prod;
}
```

Try the imput 
3
1 2
2 5
3 5
Hope you can help me, I tried to fix this code for 5h and i didn't succeed.

Comment: Your design seems wrong. Should `Vector_Complex` really *be* a `Numar_Complex`? I don't think so.

Comment: Yes, it should be so

Comment: That doesn't make sense... A container of complex numbers is not a complex number itself.

Answer (score 2):

You default-construct a `Vector_Complex` object, and your default constructor does

```
Vector_Complex::Vector_Complex() {
    len = 0;
    v = new Numar_Complex[0];
}
```

Then you read from a stream into the `Vector_Complex` object, which does

```
friend istream& operator >>(istream& in, Vector_Complex & w) {
    in >> w.len;
    for (int i = 0; i < w.len; i++)
        in >> w.v[i];
    return in;
}
```

Now, as the `Vector_Complex` object is default-constructed, the `v` variable will be a pointer to an "array" of *zero* elements. That means `w.v[i]` will be invalid for *any* value of `i`. Writing to that (with `in >> w.v[i]`) leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Thanks. That was the problem. Big up!